# Why does this code call rand() twice to get at least N random bits?

Tags: c, random

The first problem in Programming Pearls, Chapter 12, reads:

> The C library rand() function typically returns about fifteen random bits. Use that function to implement a function bigrand() to return at least 30 random bits...

and this is the solution the author gives:

```
int bigrand()
{
    return RAND_MAX*rand() + rand(); // why add the rand() in the last 
}
```

Why does the author add a call to `rand` after the multiplication?

Comment: Probably in an attempt to give more "randomness" / generate bigger numbers. `rand()` fills only the first 16-bits of an int in most implementations.

Comment: How can you produce random numbers greater than 6 if all you have is a six-sided die? How do you produce random numbers greater then `RAND_MAX` if all you have is a `RAND_MAX`-sided PRNG implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Without the additional `rand()` the result would be a multiple of `RAND_MAX` and therefore not even vaguely random.

In fact the code you show isn't quite correct it should be

```
int bigrand()
{
    return (RAND_MAX+1)*rand() + rand(); // why add the rand() in the last 
}
```

`RAND_MAX` is almost always 2^x-1 for some x. Without the `+1` there is overlap between `RAND_MAX*rand()` and `rand()` so you are effectively adding two random numbers which skews the randomness (e.g. like adding together two dice throws).

Adding the extra 1 makes it a power of 2 so `RAND_MAX*rand()` has the bottom x bits all 0; the additional `rand()` fills in the bottom bits. This is more like shifting the first rand() left and or-ing in the second.

Note that this method is OK for just generating a bit of non-critical test data but shouldn't be used if true linear randomness is required; you should be using using a true 30 bit (or more) random number generator if you need 30 bits.

Comment: yes this is to make sure in case RAND_MAX = 32767 it'll fill the whole 32 bits

Comment: using `(RAND_MAX+1)*rand() ^ rand()` is better, no overflow if `RAND_MAX > 0x7fff`

Answer (score 0):

The problem for which this is the solution reads:

> The C library rand() function typically returns about fifteen random bits. Use that function to implement a function bigrand() to return at least 30 random bits...

A straightforward way to do that is to combine the output of 2 `rand()` calls, filling the necessary number of bits, 15 at a time. This

```
RAND_MAX * rand()
```

fills the most significant 15 bits, and the addition takes care of the rest.

This of course is undefined behaviour if the value of RAND_MAX makes an `int` type overflow (on my system, I find `#define RAND_MAX 0x7fffffff`). If the `rand` specification were a bit more strict, e.g. to say that only the lowest 15 bits are random (an unlikely and fictitious scenario), we could do:

```
int bigrand(void)
{
    return ((rand() & 0x7fff) << 15) | (rand() & 0x7fff);
}
```